# How can i find index of symetric value in diagonal?

Tags: algorithm, matrix, matrix-inverse

I have created a inverse matrix in one dimensional array and I want to find out how to get index of reflect value in diagonal.

For example:
Let's say that I found value (value: 1) and I also know index of this value (index: 1). How can I find 2nd index of this value?
Let's assume that values in ths inverse matrix can be repeated.

```
const matrix: number[] = [0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 0, 4, 5, 2, 4, 0, 6, 3, 5, 6, 0];
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it a inverse matrix or a symmetric matrix? I believe what you have shown is a symmetric matrix.

Matrix inverse is defined as :

if `A*B = I` then `B` is inverse of `A` where `I` is identity matrix.

Lets assume you created a symmetric matrix , the property of such matrix is :

for each `(i,j) -> A(i,j) == A(j,i)`

Now given you represent your matrix as one dimensional array, an element at index `k` can be converted to its corresponding `(i,j)` location as :

`i = k / C`

`j = k % C`

where `C` is number of columns

and also a location `(i, j)` can be converted to its corresponding one-dimensional location as :

`k = i*R + j`

where `R` is number of rows.

Now to get the symmetric value of `(i,j)` given `k`, first convert `k` to `(i,j)` and then convert `(j,i)` to new value of `k`

`newK = j*R + i`

for example for `k = 1` corresponding `(i,j) = ( 1 / 4, 1 % 4) = (0, 1)`

and `newK = 1*4 + 0 = 4`

for `k = 6` corresponding `(i,j) = ( 6 / 4, 6 % 4) = (1, 2)`

and `newK = 2*4 + 1 = 9`

for `k = 15` corresponding `(i,j) = ( 15 / 4, 15 % 4) = (3, 3)`

and `newK = 3*4 + 3 = 15`

for `k = 5` corresponding `(i,j) = ( 5 / 4, 5 % 4) = (1, 1)`

and `newK = 1*4 + 1 = 5`

Anything that falls on diagonal would be itself.

Comment: Yes I was talking about symmetric matrix, sorry for my mistake, and thank you for good explanation mate :D